# What good interactive sites are there to learn formal higher mathematics?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, soft-question, self-learning, math-software

It seems to me that apart from some counted Moocs (where exercises are somewhat limited) a bank to study more abstract areas of mathematics, memorizing, solving problems and checking for correct proofs is lacking, the only thing that comes to mind is creating some supermemo cloze excercices to study theorems and important demonstration structures of the books of my courses, but i'm finding this lack of automation an opportunity to help more people get into higher math.

Even a page like https://www.canfigureit.com/ or the ancient https://feromax.com/cgi-bin/ProveIt.pl?task=getproofslist are of help for me, because of the very lack of rigorous background even on geometry, this may seem desperate but with the fear of having only two midterms and a final in most of the courses that will come from my department, and where all my previous knowledge helps only into my CS classes -and only the non rigorous ones-, finding this stack exchange feels like a little treasure, that I'll take it into account when I study Real analysis and Topology in the semesters to come, but i wonder for any other non human practice help...

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This question will probably be closed as much too broad - the site is for answers to particular questions. You can't just study "formal higher mathematics". I suggest you take a look at the syllabi and texts for the math courses you need to take to see if you understand the prerequisite material. You don't have to understand the material itself - that's what the course is for.

Comment: i hope it isn't i have seen other post asking for MOOC suggestions and apps, some things like indexed families seem a little complicated even after reading and doing the suggested exercises, so that's an area  along others where i would love to find more online (hopefully interactive) resources

Comment: I don't know if [Mizar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mizar) would help you? They have their articles [HTML-linked](http://www.mizar.org/version/current/html/) where you can learn a lot, since the proofs can be unfolded, used theorems can be shown by hovering and if you find an unknown notion, click on it to get to the definition. The article list is just a bit random, you will have to know where to look or explore it yourself. For a start, I really learned about ordinals with [this article](http://www.mizar.org/version/current/html/ordinal1.html).